# How do I limit the decimal places before "e"?

Tags: c++, printf

I want to print a float variable x in C++ in the format "1.00e6", where I only want 2 places after the decimal point before the e.

Reading over this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/, I'm not sure which specifier to use. Can this be done in C++?

Comment: Why are you using `printf`?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: There's nothing inherently wrong with using `printf()`.  It's easier to localize than `<iostream>`.  Modern compilers will type check it.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: "Idiomatic" is inherently subjective.  Not everyone agrees whether to use `<iostream>` or `<cstdio>`, and this is not the forum to have this discussion.  Please stick to facts instead of opinions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the same in C++:

```
 double f = 1.00e6;
 std::cout.precision(2);
 std::cout << std::scientific;
 std::cout<<f <<std::endl;
 It will output: 1.00e+06 in this case.
```

**EDIT**: as pointed out by @user657267, There's a manipulator for `precision` as well,

```
 double f = 1.00e6;
 std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::scientific << f << '\n';
```

should have same effect.

Comment: There's a manipulator for `precision` as well, `std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::scientific << f << '\n';`

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation for `printf()` with `man 3 printf` if you are on any Unix-like system (OS X, Linux, BSD, etc.)  In general, you specify precision with `.N`, where `N` is the desired precision:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%.2e\n", 1.0);
}
```

Output:

```
1.00e+00
```

I've given the code in C, since this is really a question about the C standard library which is part of the C++ standard by reference.